calculate $\frac{|Cl_{GL_n(\mathbb{F})}(A)|}{|Cl_{SL_n(\mathbb{F})}(A)|}$ for a given $A\in SL_n(\mathbb{F})$, $\mathbb{F}$ is a finite field
I'll restate the problem, with all the assumption, for your convenience.
calculate $\frac{|Cl_{GL_n(\mathbb{F})}(A)|}{|Cl_{SL_n(\mathbb{F})}(A)|}$ for a given $A\in SL_n(\mathbb{F})$, $\mathbb{F}$ is a finite field, $n >= 2$, and $A$'s minimal polynomial satisifies $deg(\mu_A)=n-1$.
this is an homework question I got on my modules theory course, In the course itself the lecturer developed the following statement:
$$
\frac{|Cl_{GL_n(\mathbb{F})}(A)|}{|Cl_{SL_n(\mathbb{F})}(A)|}=[F^*:det(Centralizer_{GL_n}(A))]
$$
this is true because of the first isomorphism theorem, orbit-stabillizer theorem and lagrange's theorem.(I can prove the result if neccesary).
I am trying to use this result to solve my problem, I already know that the degree of the minimal polynomial of A determines the rational canonical form of A to be a 2-diagonally block matrix
where the of the form $Diag(C(x-a),C(\mu_A))$, where $(x-a) | \mu_A$ , and $C(f)$ is the companion matrix of f, but here is where I am stuck, I dont know how to proceed from here...
any hints or directions of proof are more than welcome.

After putting $A$ into rational canonical form, we see that its centralizer contains diagonal matrices with entries $(\lambda,1,1,\ldots,1)$ for all $\lambda \in F^*$, so $|F^*:C|=1$, where $C = \langle \det x : x \in C_{{\rm GL}(n,F)}(A) \rangle$.

Thank you so much,  I was wondering, knowing that the determinant of A is 1, and is of the form $Diag(C(x-a),C(\mu_A))$ can I claim that $Diag(\lambda * a,C(\mu_A))$ commutes with A?
